# How can I upgrade Pitivi to 0.94?

Tags: updates, pitivi

In Ubuntu 14.10, every time I open Pitivi it says "Pitivi 0.94 is available" but there doesn't seem to be a way to upgrade to it. I want to try out Pitivi again, because they seem to be making huge improvements, but I always like to have the latest.

Comment: what is the result of `sudo apt-get install pitivi`?

Answer (score 2):

PiTiVi is correct in that a new version is available, but it fails to tell you that it's not available from the package management system. The latest version on Ubuntu is [0.93](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=vivid&keywords=pitivi) (for 15.04). For a newer version, you'd have to [install from source](http://www.pitivi.org/?go=download), or download an [all-in-one precompiled bundle](http://fundraiser.pitivi.org/download-bundles). I couldn't find any PPAs with the latest version.